# Socket.IO Sever send to both clients

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have got a node server running locally and setting up a Socket.IO instance.

```
const http = require('http');
const socket = require('socket.io');
const path = require('path');

class Controller
{
    constructor() {

        this.localURL = path.resolve(process.cwd() + '/themes/');
        this.theme = null;

        const server = http.createServer();
        this.io = new socket.Server(server, {
            transports: ['websocket'],
        });

        this.io.on("connection", socket => {
            // Wait for the client to send the website theme
            socket.on('init', theme => {

                // Inform current running client that the server is changing projects.
                if (this.theme && this.theme !== theme) {
                    socket.emit(`message-${this.theme}`, {
                        type: 'message',
                        message: `Project changed to ${theme}, stopping ${this.theme}.`
                    });
                    return;
                }

                // Set the theme
                this.theme = theme;
            });
        });
        server.listen(8080);
    }
}
new Controller();
```

Then on my website I have got a Vue component, but sometimes I could have 2 of the components, so I wanted to emit messages to BOTH of these component's from my server, I will handle accepting the messages in either Vue Instance myself.

This was working, all of a sudden it's not now, not too sure what I changed.

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
export default {
    props: [ 'code' ],
    mounted: function () {
        this.socket = io('ws://localhost:8080', {
            forceNew: true,
            timeout: 10000,
            transports: ['websocket']
        });
        this.socket.on('connect', () => {
            this.connected = true;
        });
        this.socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            this.connected = false;
            this.initiated = false;
        });
        this.socket.on(`stop-${this.code}`, () => {
            this.started = '';
        });
        this.socket.on(`message-${this.code}`, message => {
            console.log(message);
            message.time = 'N/A';
            this.messages.unshift(message);
        })

        this.socket.onAny((event, data) => {
            if (event.indexOf(this.code) > -1) {
                return;
            }
            event = event.replace(`-${this.code}`, '');
            this[event] = data;
        });
    },
    methods: {
        initiate() {
            this.messages = [];
            this.socket.emit('init', this.code);
            this.socket.on('started', code => {
                if (code !== this.code) {
                    console.log('Themes don\'t match...');
                    this.initiated = false;
                    return;
                }
```

So initially I would run `initiate` on one of the components, this sends some the theme name to the server and the server stores the theme in a property. Then I would run `initiate` on the second component, which would send a different theme, so this should hit the `this.theme && this.theme !== theme` if, and send a message back to the initial theme.

This message is being sent and the `event` names are as expected, but nothing comes through on the component.

Comment: What is `>!`? I don't think I've ever seen that before.

Comment: Are you aware that you `return;` before updating `this.theme` in the `if` you mentioned?

Comment: what is `this.code` and why do you use an event name like \`message-${`this.code`}\` ? it's really works? I don't think so

Comment: @ChrisHayes Corrected the `>!` however this did work for some reason...

Comment: @Cem I only return if the servers `theme` has already been set, so the first time `init` is ran that if will be missed and `theme` will get set.

Comment: @DaniilLoban so I know which instance of the client the message is for

Comment: aha, I have got it, how do you pass data from component?

Comment: does it happen only when `init` this.socket.emit('init', this.code); ?